# How to pass PHP variable as FlashVars via SWFObject

Tags: php, flash, swfobject, actionscript-3

I am trying to take a PHP variable and pass it along to Flash via Flash vars. My end goal is to pass a string formatted as XML to Flash, but because I'm struggling I've stripped everything down to the basics. I'm just trying to pass a simple PHP string variable to Flash via FlashVars with SWFObject but something isn't right. The page won't load when I try to pass the variable inside of php tags, but it will load if I just pass a hard coded string. The basic structure of my page is that I have some PHP declared at the top like so:

PHP

```
<?php
     $test = "WTF";
?>
```

Some HTML (excluded here for simplicity sake) and then the JavaScript SWFObject Embed within my HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        var swfURL = "swfs/Init-Flash-PHP.swf";

        var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.theXML = <?php print $test ?>;

        var params = {};
            //params.menu = "false";
            params.scale = "showAll";
            params.bgcolor = "#000000";
            params.salign = "TL";
            //params.wmode = "transparent";
            params.allowFullScreen = "true";
            params.allowScriptAccess = "always";

        var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "container";
            attributes.name = "container";


        swfobject.embedSWF(swfURL, "container", '100%', '100%', "9.0.246", "elements/swfs/expressinstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);


        // ]]>
</script>
```

And the bare essentials of the ActionScript 3 Code:

```
_paramObj = LoaderInfo(stage.loaderInfo).parameters;
theText_txt.text = _paramObj['theXML'];
```

How do I pass a PHP variable using SWFObject and FlashVars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh, I needed to escape the Flash vars and it worked.

For anyone that's interested, this is what I needed to change

```
flashvars.theXML = <?php print $test ?>;
```

To this:

```
flashvars.theXML = escape('<?php print $test ?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

escape() is not a foolproof way to escape (!)

Use encodeURIComponent() instead.

This is from point 9 at the FAQ: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq

> 9. How can I pass URIs or HTML code as a value using flashvars?
>
> Special characters and the symbols =
>   and & cannot directly be used inside
>   flashvars values (the latter because
>   they are used to stack the flashvars
>   themselves).
>
> You can workaround this issue by
>   escaping these characters before
>   passing them as flashvar values. An
>   example:
>
> encodeURIComponent("&trade") will
>   become %26trade
>
> The values will be available in your
>   swf already unencoded, so no
>   unescaping is needed inside your swf.
>
> Note that encodeURIComponent is not
>   available in all browsers, but is
>   available in all of the common modern
>   versions. If you need full backwards
>   compatibility, you can use escape()
>   instead, but note that escape() does
>   not work well with double-byte
>   characters (like Chinese).
>
> You can also escape these characters
>   manually by using:
>
> ```
> * %3D instead of =
> * %26 instead of &
> ```