# Pass php $_GET to flash player xml file

Tags: php, javascript, flash, actionscript, get

I have a flash player embedded on page x.php?user=john using swfobject. The player calls the xml file content.php to get the results. in content.php i have $_GET['user']. I'm trying to get the user name from the url id and fetch results based on that. I'm however getting a 500 error. I don't think content.php is able to access the `user` variable. if i just put in the username "john" instead of $_GET['user'] then it works. How can i get this to work with $_GET['user']

XML file content.php looks like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.videote as videote, b.user_name as user_name'. 
' FROM '.$video.' as a,'.$users.' as b'.
' where b.user_name=$_GET['user'] and... //if i replace $_GET['user'] with john then it works
```

In x.php flash is embeded like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var so = new SWFObject("play2.swf", "sotester", "1000", "400", "8", "#000000");
    so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
    so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
    so.addParam("menu", "false");
    so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

My Player Actionscript is of course pointing to content.php which is not the issue here

```
xmlData.load("contentp.php");
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of code? Also, is the server error returned when loading x.php or content.php?

Comment: @GargantuChe also 500 error is resulting from content.php not x.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinkie, thanks for posting the code.

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.videote as videote, b.user_name as user_name'. 
    ' FROM '.$video.' as a,'.$users.' as b'.
    ' where b.user_name=$_GET['user'] and... //if i replace $_GET['user'] with john then it works
```

There are a few issues here, but we can work through them.

A syntax error is introduced when you change the string. You have the right idea with the way `$video` and `$users`. But when adding the `$_GET['user']`, PHP thinks that the first apostrophe is ending the current string.

Consider that:

```
' where b.user_name=$_GET['user'] and...'
```

looks like two strings, separated by the word "user":

```
' where b.user_name=$_GET[' user '] and...'
```

This isn't proper syntax, so the 500 error is returned. I'm guessing that your error would go away if you tried:

```
' where b.user_name=' . $_GET['user'] . ' and...'
```

The next issue is that if a user were to send a carefully crafted value for the "user" parameter, they could cause the query to behave in a way that you didn't intend.

Try this: create a file called login.php, with the following content:

```
<?php
    // Just display the output; no HTML formatting needed
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    // This must succeed, or mysql_real_escape_string() won't have any effect
    mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
        OR die(mysql_error());

    $safeQuery = 'SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user=\'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']) . '\' AND pass=\'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']) . '\';';
    echo "  safeQuery is: $safeQuery\n";

    $unsafeQuery = 'SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user=\'' . $_GET['username'] . '\' AND pass=\'' . $_GET['password'] . '\';';
    echo "unsafeQuery is: $unsafeQuery\n";
?>
```

Load `login.php?username=bob&password=sample`. The output looks reasonable:

```
  safeQuery is: SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user='bob' AND pass='sample';
unsafeQuery is: SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user='bob' AND pass='sample';
```

Now try loading `login.php?username=bob&password=sample' OR 'hello'='hello"`:

```
  safeQuery is: SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user='bob' AND pass='sample\' OR \'hello\'=\'hello';
unsafeQuery is: SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user='bob' AND pass='sample' OR 'hello'='hello';
```

The safe query will return zero, unless you have a user called bob whose password really is `sample' OR 'hello'='hello"`.

The unsafe version, however, will return the total count of users in the database. The WHERE clause is now:

```
WHERE user='bob' AND pass='sample' OR 'hello'='hello'
```

The `OR 'hello'='hello'` will make the condition true in all cases, even if `bob` doesn't exist or has a password other than `sample`.

Part of your query could even be commented out. Try `login.php?username=bob' --`:

```
  safeQuery is: SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user='bob\' --' AND pass='';
unsafeQuery is: SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user='bob' --' AND pass='';
```

The password parameter is now ignored, because it's embedded within a SQL comment.

So even if you're just executing a SELECT statement, the results can be manipulated by a clever user if their inputs weren't escaped.

You can use mysql_real_escape_string to protect against such bad values. This function will add backslashes where necessary to keep input data from being executed as SQL.

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.videote as videote, b.user_name as user_name'. 
    ' FROM '.$video.' as a,'.$users.' as b'.
    ' where b.user_name=\'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']) . '\' and...';
```

Example 1 from the [php.net page for mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) has a great example using sprintf:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($user),
    mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Each `%s` is replaced with the parameters (in the order they are specified). This makes it easier to keep your query readable, while protecting against bad input data.

Comment: Great. You got it. Concatenation was definitely an issue. Along with other things i did, it works now.

Comment: i'm Just wondering why do i need to use mysql_real_string_escape knowing that i'm only selecting and not inserting. Can you clarify.

Comment: @Pinkie, I updated the post to include examples. The short version is that a user could disable or alter your WHERE clause, and cause the query to return just about anything they wanted. Let me know if it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and examples. It's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm reading this correctly, when a user visits the page at x.php?user=john, your server is returning a page that contains a flash object.  That flash object in turn attempts to load the xml page at content.php.  You are correct that content.php cannot access any of the $_GET variables from x.php, because they are two completely different requests.

There are two things that you could do:

1. Put the contents of $_GET['user'] into the page as a <param> and then have your flash object add that to its request.
2. Have flash get the information from the query string using the technique [from this other article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184990/how-can-i-use-url-parameters-while-debugging-in-flash-builder-4).

I feel this deserves a warning though, please remember to sanitize the contents of the query string before using it, so that you won't end up with a CSS or SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @JoshuaRogers Can you clarify your answer. How i put my $_GET as a <param> and how i have the flash object add that to it's request. I wouldn't be asking if knew the answers.

Comment: In x.php, add so.addParam("user", "<?php print urlencode($_GET['user']) ?>");  Within your .as, you would change the code to load as follows:  var user:String = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("user");  xmlData.load("content.php?user=" + user);  You should be aware, however, the code above is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Should the user add ?user="Jim"; DELETE FROM users, you would likely find the users table wiped clean. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php/] I'd recommend PHP's addslashes.

Comment: Also, it appears that content.php is failing because there should be quotes around the $_GET['user'] in your SQL.

Comment: @JoshuaRogers i added addParam and also modified the .as file as per your instruction. I not getting results although the 500 error is gone now. You didn't mention anything about the sql query. Do i just keep it as `b.user_name=\'$_GET["user"]\'`

Comment: @JoshuaRogers Looking at the request logs i see Request URL:`http://domain.com/contentp.php?user=undefined`. I'm getting undefined. I'm not so sure user s being passed correctly. Any ideas. By the way i have `var user:String = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("user"); ` in my `.as` file. Is this correct. I'm assuming that's where it should go

Comment: I think @Tomas has a better answer, above.

Comment: @Pinkie, after adding so.addParam, does the page HTML now contain the username?

Answer (score 1):

So Joshua definitely has the right idea, but let me see if I can clarify and expand on it a little.

Essentially you should pass the GET variable to flash using the flash vars param (you can read an excellent tutorial on it [here](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/index.html)). Once flash has the variable it should append the query for content.php with `?yourNewGetVariable=ValuePassedOnToFlash`, and Joshua is right before you pass on that value you should definitely [sanitize](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10356594) it and [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it for URL's. Then your content.php file should have no problem accessing `yourNewGetVariable`

Comment: The link you refered me to is not using swfobject. As per @JoshuaRogers help, i `added so.addParam("user", "<?php print urlencode($_GET['user']) ?>");` as an swfobject parameter and in my .as file i added `var user:String = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("user");` and modified  `xmlData.load("content.php?user=" + user);` In my sql query i have `b.user_name=\'$_GET["user"]\'` now when i run the player looking at the request logs i see `http://domain.com/contentp.php?user=undefined`. Not getting results. Any idea why i'm getting undefined.

Comment: @Pinkie, sorry for the bad link as, as far as your new problem goes I believe (but I'm no expert) that variables should be passed using flashvars as written about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899765/how-to-pass-php-variable-as-flashvars-via-swfobject) and [here](http://www.flashmagazine.com/tutorials/detail/passing_parameters_to_flash_using_javascript/)